# Anonymous Blade Component - Rendering slot variable to function yields array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Laravel 7.X

I've created a simple anonymous input blade component that includes validation error output.  It was a translation of a previously working template.

The component is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for='{{$field}}'>{{$title}} @error($field) - <span class='text-danger'> {{ $message }} </span> @enderror </label>
    <input id='{{$field}}' name='{{$field}}' type="text" class='form-control{{ $errors->has($field) ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}' placeholder='{{$placeholder}}' {{$attributes}} value='{{ old($field, $value) }}' >
</div>
```

In the view, I do the following:

```
<x-input-validation autofocus onblur="validate()">
    <x-slot name="field">name</x-slot>
    <x-slot name="title">Name</x-slot>
    <x-slot name="placeholder">Add Name</x-slot>
    <x-slot name="value">{{$app->name}}</x-slot>
</x-input-validation>
```

During rendering, I receive the following error message:

```
array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer (View: C:\wamp64\www\DE\resources\views\components\input-validation.blade.php)
```

The problem seems to be related to the @error($field) directive and the old($field, $value) function.  If I change these to remove the $field variable, it will render.

It also seems to work, unaltered, if there are no validation errors present, or if there aren't previous values stored in the session.  It renders properly under this situation, too.

After many tries, one tidbit seems to be that the $field variable is of type HTMLString.  Not sure if this is a red herring or not, but given it's complaining about type, I'm assuming that's the source of the problem.

Any ideas how I should correct this issue?  I'm stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: I've been able to resolve this problem by using html_entity_decode($field) in each of the @error, $error->has($field) and old($field, $value) functions.  It is now working.  Kind of not expected, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this problem by using html_entity_decode($field) in each of the @error, $error->has($field) and old($field, $value) functions.

Since $field was an instance of HTMLString, html_entity_decode returns a string, acceptable to these functions.  While $field contained only characters, other than type conversion, I see no other change to the content of $field.

The new component becomes:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for='{{$field}}'>{{$title}} @error(html_entity_decode($field)) - <span class='text-danger'> {{ $message }} </span> @enderror </label>
    <input id='{{$field}}' name='{{$field}}' type="text" class='form-control{{ $errors->has(html_entity_decode($field)) ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}' placeholder='{{$placeholder}}' {{$attributes}} value='{{ old(html_entity_decode($field), $value) }}' >
</div>
```

This addresses the problem.  I can't help but think this is more of an oversight with Laravel handling this case.